# Unix bash script grep loop counter (for)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am looping our the a grep result. The result contains 10 lines (every line has different content). So the loop stuff in the loop gets executed 10 times.

I need to get the index, 0-9, in the run so i can do actions based on the index.

```
ABC=(cat test.log | grep "stuff")

counter=0
for x in $ABC
do
        echo $x      
        ((counter++))
        echo "COUNTER $counter"
done
```

Currently the counter won't really change.

Output:

```
51209
120049
148480
1211441
373948
0
0
0
728304
0
COUNTER: 1
```

Comment: `i can do actions based on the index`: What action do you want to do? Your output doesn't like coming from the script shown. Your `echo` command has a `:` which is not appearing in output.

Comment: Is `ABS` a variable, or an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell script contains what should be an obvious syntax error.

```
ABC=(cat test.log | grep "stuff")
```

This fails with

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

There is no need to save the output in a variable if you only want to process one at a time (and obviously no need for  the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)).

```sh
grep "stuff" test.log | nl
```

gets you numbered lines, though the index will be 1-based, not zero-based.

If you absolutely need zero-based, refactoring to Awk should solve it easily:

```sh
awk '/stuff/ { print n++, $0 }' test.log
```

If you want to loop over this and do something more with this information,

```sh
awk '/stuff/ { print n++, $0 }' test.log |
while read -r index output; do
    echo index is "$index"
    echo output is "$output"
done
```

Because the `while` loop executes in a subshell the value of `index` will not be visible outside of the loop. (I guess that's what your real code did with the counter as well. I don't think that part of the code you posted will repro either.)

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is to only print counter(which is as per shown samples only), in that case you could use `awk`(if you are ok with it), this could be done in a single `awk` like, without creating variable and then using `grep` like you are doing currently, `awk` could perform both search and counter printing in a single shot.

```
awk -v counter=0 '/stuff/{print "counter=" counter++}' Input_file
```

Replace `stuff` string above with the actual string you are looking for and place your actual file name for Input_file in above.

This should print like:

```
counter=1
counter=2
........and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not store the result of `grep` in a scalar variable $ABC.
If the line of the log file contains whitespaces, the variable $x
is split on them due to the `word splitting` of `bash`.
(BTW the statement `ABC=(cat test.log | grep "stuff")` causes a syntax error.)

Please try something like:

```
readarray -t abc < <(grep "stuff" test.log)

for x in "${abc[@]}"
do
    echo "$x"
    echo "COUNTER $((++counter))"
done
```

or

```
readarray -t abc < <(grep "stuff" test.log)

for i in "${!abc[@]}"
do
    echo "${abc[i]}"
    echo "COUNTER $((i + 1))"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below increment statement-

```
counter=$(( $counter + 1));
```

Comment: Right. but `((counter++))` does work as well.